# Converting AM/PM time stored as text in to military time

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have excel sheet report with several hundreds of lines and in one of the cells I have time value stored as AM/PM.

The problem is that cell values are as stored as a text values and I can’t change it as it is generated from the system as is.
I need to sort the sheet by time to be able to work on it, but problem is, for example 01:00 PM will come before 09:00 AM or 08:00 AM, etc.

Now I have some code to get around this:

```
Sub DepTime()
'12:00 AM
With Range("D1:D1000")
    Set c = .Find("12:00 AM", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Activate
            c.Value = "00:00"
            Set c = .FindNext
            If c Is Nothing Then
                GoTo SearchTime2
            End If
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
SearchTime2:
End With
'12:15 AM
With Range("d1:d1000")
    Set c = .Find("12:15 AM", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Activate
            c.Value = "00:15"
            Set c = .FindNext
            If c Is Nothing Then
                GoTo SearchTime3
            End If
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
SearchTime3:

... Code goes like this all the way to 11:45pm...

End With
End Sub
```

Code goes all the way to 11:45pm...
I spent hours doing this; it helps, but there must be abetter way of doing it... Also, i only have code for 15min intervals of time, but if I get a specific time like 1:13 PM, it does not help me... Is there a way to convert any given time from text to military time...

Any assistance would be super appreciated.

Comment: `format(Now, "hh:mm")`

Comment: If you want to do this in Formula (VBA free): `=TEXT(C2,"HH:MM")`, if all combined with Date and time to be sorted, use something like `"YYYY.MM.DD.HH.MM"`

Comment: thanks braX, but it doesnt work for me... it formats the cell properties, but does not get rid of the AM/PM so it stays stored as a 01:00 AM/PM etc...

If I would now manually enter the time in the cell it would format it correctly, but as said, i have hundreds of lines... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once more I want to thank everyone who posted a reply and took their time to help out. I finaly figure out why it wasn't working... Since iported from RTF, I had space at begining and end of time value which i haven't noticed... :(

Anways, this is my workig solution:

```
Sub DepTime()

    Range("D1:D1000").Select

    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Selection

    For Each cell In A
    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)
    Next

    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the format as @braX mentioned and then use `.TextToColumns` to format the entire range/column in one go. No loops required.

In below example, I am assuming the data is in Col A in Sheet1. Change as applicable.

```
With Sheet1
    With .Columns(1)
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
        .TextToColumns Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With
End With
```

BTW, you do not need VBA for this. You can do the same thing in a few mouse clicks as well as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So to go with what you saying you want to convert all these text's that look like time to real timevalues without the AM/PM formatting?

@SiddharthRout have given an easy example how to do so. Here is an alternative way:

---

You can loop through a range of cells in your column and use [`Timevalue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timevalue-function) with [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) functions to re-arrange your data:

```
Sub Test1()

Dim rng As Range, lr As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr)
    rng.NumberFormat = "HH:MM"
    For Each cl In rng
        cl.Value = Format(TimeValue(cl.Value), "HH:MM")
    Next cl
End With

End Sub
```

---

You can achieve the same thing to do it in one go with the help of [`.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate):

```
Sub Test2()

Dim rng As Range, lr As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr)
    rng.NumberFormat = "HH:MM"
    rng.Value = .Evaluate("=TEXT(TIMEVALUE(" & rng.Address & "), ""HH:MM"")")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ++Prefer Test2 over test1 :P

Answer (score 0):

I want to say big thank you to all of you for your time and suggestions, but unfortunately none is working for me. :(

All the methods mentioned above are doing needfull and add correct properties to the cells. So if I now click on any of the cells and manualy re-type, for example 1:30 PM - IT WILL INDEED CONVERT to 13:30, but none of the cells that already contain time information will change - they still remain as 1:30 PM (or whatever info they contain).

Not sure if I have to mention that I get the report in RTF file and I have my macro importing and formating everything to excell. I have everything else working, except fot the time column. I just can't get around it... :(

Comment: Can you actually edit your question to include a screenshot of your data, or at least a sample data of your column with supposedly time values...

Answer (score 0):

So here you can see the output of any of above methods.

[image]

As you can see if I manually click on cells and enter the time, it converts to military time exactly as I wanted. However, none of the cells already filled out are converting automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this function will help ....

```
Sub DepTime()

  Dim cel As Object
  Dim lr As Long: lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
  For Each cel In Range("C1:C" & lr)
     cel.Value = Format(CDate(cel.Value), "HH:mm")
  Next 
End Sub
```